# How to get a msg returned from form post in html

Tags: javascript, json, html, web-services

I'm trying to get a msg returned from server in form using html.

For example:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/Test/ws/site/validateUser">
...
</form>
```

The server process and return a msg in JSON. But I'm not getting the msg returned from server.

How can I get the msg?

Comment: How does the server return the message? In case if it is through a webservice, then you need to make a ajax call for posting your data and to receive the server response through a callback.

Comment: I just want to print the msg to user from webservice response. I already tried to use ajax but it not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form method you are using, will result in redirect the page to the webservice URL not returing the result json message.

to call the webservice and get the response message in the same page, you can use JQuery ajax
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

the following js code will call the HTTP webservice, using the data in the form and the result value will be stored in msg variable and you can parse it using
[JSON.parse](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#yourForm" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/Test/ws/site/validateUser',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $("#yourForm").serialize(),
            success : function( msg )
            {
                alert(msg);
                msg = JSON.parse(msg);
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The html form will be

```
<form id="yourForm">
....
</form>
```

Comment: @DanielPereira Sorry there was a missing i in serialize, corrected :)
please try it.